# How to validate if a checkbox has been checked on an AJAX/PHP form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am stuck trying to validate if a checkbox has been selected using an AJAX form submit. Essentially I want to make sure that either the standard rate or the emergency rate checkbox is checked (because only one of them will show up from earlier code). I have tried .val() like the others but it doesn't work either. Also, the select doesn't work. But my guess is that the checkbox and select are from the same problem.

HTML Code:

```
<li class="standard-rate rate">
    <input type="checkbox" name="acknowledge-standard-rate" value="Standard Rate" id="acknowledge-standard-rate"><div class="standard-rate-desc">(*)I acknowledge time spent on my request will be deducted from my current contract or, in the absence of an hourly pack, billed at the end of the month.</div>
</li>

<li class="emergency-rate rate">
    <input  type="checkbox" name="acknowledge-emergency-rate" value="Emergency Rate" id="acknowledge-emergency-rate"><div class="emergency-rate-desc">(*)I acknowledge time spent on my request will be billed at our $200/hour emergency rate.</div>
</li>
```

AJAX/jQuery Code:

```
var formData = {
    'first_name'        : $('input[name=first_name]').val(),
    'last_name'         : $('input[name=last_name]').val(),
    'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
    'phone'             : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
    'message'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
    'severity'          : $('select[name=severity]').val(),
    'acknowledge-standard-rate'     : $('input[name=acknowledge-standard-rate]').is(':checked'),
    'acknowledge-emergency-rate'    : $('input[name=acknowledge-emergency-rate]').is(':checked')
    };

// process the form
    var request = $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true
    })
```

PHP code from process.php

```
if (!isset($_POST['acknowledge-standard-rate']) && !isset($_POST['acknowledge-emergency-rate'])) {// if
  //doing null check for checkbox and returning one
  $errors['checkbox'] = 'Please check the check box aknowledging payment.';
} // if
```

Comment: if you need to ensure that one or other is checked perhaps a radio button would be better

Comment: It would still run into the same issue though. Because that form data would still recognize it as a value. Select statements would also run into the same issue.

Comment: If the radio buttons share a common name but have different values then you are guaranteed that field will be populated in the POST array. Alternatively, set a hidden radio button for the default

Comment: also adding the attribute required="required" to a field will make it required https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute

Comment: You still run into the same issue because I need to see if it is checked just like with this checkbox.

Comment: I also might recommend validating the form prior to submit on the client-side(jquery might be easiest) to reduce the load on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here I think is that you are always setting a value `true or false` into both of those checkbox fields in you javascript.

Default browser form processing would not actually send the variable at all if it was not checked and your PHP code would work.

So instead of always creating these 2 variables

```
'acknowledge-standard-rate'     : $('input[name=acknowledge-standard-rate]').is(':checked'),
'acknowledge-emergency-rate'    : $('input[name=acknowledge-emergency-rate]').is(':checked')
};
```

In you javascript, you need to only create them if the relevant checkbox is checked.

Maybe something like this

```
var formData = {
    'first_name'        : $('input[name=first_name]').val(),
    'last_name'         : $('input[name=last_name]').val(),
    'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
    'phone'             : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
    'message'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
    'severity'          : $('select[name=severity]').val()
};
if ( $('input[name=acknowledge-standard-rate]').is(':checked') ) {
    formData.acknowledge-standard-rate = $('input[name=acknowledge-standard-rate]').val();
}
if ( $('input[name=acknowledge-emergency-rate]').is(':checked') ) {
    formData.acknowledge-emergency-rate = $('input[name=acknowledge-emergency-rate'].val();
}

process the form
var request = $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST', 
        url      : 'process.php',
        data     : formData, 
        dataType : 'json', 
        encode   : true
});
```

You might also want to validate that one of these is actually checked in the javascript before even starting this AJAX process, giving a simple error dialog telling the user to pick one.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Took me a long time to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_POST['acknowledge-standard-rate'] == false && $_POST['acknowledge-emergency-rate'] == false) {// if
    //doing null check for checkbox and returning one
    $errors['checkbox'] = 'Please check the check box aknowledging payment.';  
}
```

Comment: could you add console.log(formData) before ajax in your js and post result from console here?